# What is the probability that the first 8 in the deck is one of the first $6$ cards in the deck?

Tags: probability

A deck of cards is shuffled. What is the probability that the first 8 in the deck is one of the first $6$ cards in the deck?

Here's what I got,

For the first $6$ spots, you can have $\binom{6}{1}$ ways to put the $8$, and there are $4$ possible $8$'s in the deck, the remaining $5$ spots have $48 \cdot 47 \cdot 46 \cdot 45 \cdot 44$ possibilities.  For the remaining $46$ spots, you have $46!$ ways.

So the answer is  $$\frac{\binom{6}{1} \cdot 4 \cdot 48 \cdot 47 \cdot 46 \cdot 45 \cdot 44 \cdot 46!}{52!}$$ 
Am I right ?

Comment: This calculates the probability that the first $8$ is in the first $6$ cards, and no other $8$s appear.  What if two $8$s are among the first six cards?  Or all four?  (Maybe consider calculating the complement probability and subtract it from $1$.)

Comment: Isn't this what I'm looking for? Can you elaborate on what's wrong with my approach

Comment: If I use the complement approach, I will have 1-  48*47*46*45*44*43*46! / 52!

Comment: I think your complement answer is correct.

Comment: @John can you tell me what's wrong with my first approach?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: N.F. Taussig explained in his answer what was lacking in your first approach. (You covered some of the cases, but not all of them.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you could draw as many as four $8$'s among the first six cards, it is easier to compute the probability of the complementary event.  The probability of not drawing an $8$ among the first six cards is equal to the probability of selecting six of the other $48$ cards in the deck, which is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{48}{6}}{\dbinom{52}{6}}$$
Hence, the probability of selecting an $8$ among the first six cards is 
$$1 - \frac{\dbinom{48}{6}}{\dbinom{52}{6}}$$
To do the problem directly, you would have to add the following probabilities:

- one of the four $8$'s and five of the other $48$ cards when six cards are drawn
- two of the four $8$'s and four of the other $48$ cards when six cards are drawn
- three of the four $8$'s and three of the other $48$ cards when six cards are drawn
- all four $8$'s and two of the other $48$ cards when six cards are drawn